# Delay enter animation of a single element, but not exit animation using <AnimatePresence>

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I've looked at the docs, but I can't figure out how to delay only the enter animation of an element. For context, I'm trying to delay displaying a loading state, but immediately show the exit state for the loading indicator without delays. Is this possible to do with framer-motion? Thanks!

```js
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion"

export const MyComponent = ({ isVisible }) => (
  <AnimatePresence>
    {isVisible && (
      <motion.div
        id="loading-element"
        initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1 }} // I wish to delay ONLY this one
        exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
        transition={{ delay: 1 }} // this will delay ALL animations
      />
    )}
    {isVisible && (
      <motion.div
        id="content"
        initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
      />
    )}
  </AnimatePresence>
)
```